# Conversion from unsigned long long to unsigned int in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, hash

If I write the following code in C/C++:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
auto time = high_resolution_clock::now();
unsigned long long foo = time.time_since_epoch().count();
unsigned bar = foo;
```

Which bits of foo are dropped in the conversion to unsigned int? Is there any way I can enforce only the least significant bits to be preserved?

Alternatively, is there a simple way to hash foo into an unsigned int size? (This would be preferred, but I'm doing all of this in an initializer list.)

EDIT:  Just realized that preserving the least significant bits could still allow looping. I gues hashing is what I'd be going for then.

2nd EDIT:  To clarify what I responded in a comment, I am seeding std::default_random_engine inside a loop and do not want an overflow to cause seed values to repeat. I am looking for a simple way to hash unsigned long long into unsigned int.

Comment: Lowest bits are preserved by default.

Comment: What are the desired properties of the hash? `foo %` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647_(number)  springs to mind.

Comment: Thanks! I just edited the post, though. I actually want to use hashing to prevent overflow.

Comment: It sounds like you have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)....

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I want to use this to seed std::default_random_engine, and I don't want the seed values to repeat.

Comment: @Hurkyl Whoops. Yeah, I guess I did fall right into that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news you're safe:

1. I just ran `time.time_since_epoch().count()` and got:

> 1,465,934,400

2. You've got a while till you have till you see a repeat value since `numeric_limits is:

> 4,294,967,295

3. [Copying to a integral type of a smaller size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#C-like_languages):

> Causes dropping of excess higher order bits

So if you just do `static_cast<unsigned int>(foo)` you won't get a matching output for roughly 136 years: `numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max / 60U / 60U / 24U / 356U`

PS You won't care if you get a repeat by then.

Answer (score 6):

Arithmetic with unsigned integral types in C and in C++ deals with out of range values by modular reduction; e.g. if `unsigned int` is a 32 bit type, then when assigned a value out of range, it reduces the value modulo `2^32` and stores the least nonnegative representative.

In particular, that is exactly what the standard mandates when assigning from a larger to a smaller unsigned integral type.

Note also that the standard doesn't guarantee the size of `unsigned int` — if you need, for example, a type that is definitely exactly 32 bits wide, use `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Replying to the question in edit two, you can seed based on the delta between when you started and when the seed is needed. E.g.:

```
std::default_random_engine generator;
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock myclock;
myclock::time_point beginning = myclock::now();
for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) // or whatever type of loop you're using
{
    // obtain a seed from the timer
    myclock::duration d = myclock::now() - beginning;
    unsigned seed = d.count();
    generator.seed(seed);
    // TODO: magic
}
```

Comment: This is pretty nice. Unfortunately, I am doing this inside a class constructor and do not have access to the starting time (unless I pass it in to the constructor, which I do not want to do).

Comment: That's not a problem, just get the time at the start of the ctor. It doesn't have to be the beginning of the app, just some point before your for loop and in scope.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've settled on using `std::hash`.

```
std::hash<long long> seeder;
auto seed = seeder(time.time_since_epoch().count());
```

Since I am doing this in an initializer list, this can be put together in one line and passed to `std::default_random_engine` (but that looks pretty ugly).

This is quit a hit to performance, but at least it reduces the chance of seeds repeating.

Comment: As is mentioned in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37845145/2642059) You needn't worry about seeds repeating. that only happens every 139 years. And it is already linear (the best way to avoid repetition.) It's interesting but, because your hash will not have a deterministic pattern you have actually *increased* the likelihood of finding a duplicate :(